# I want to do that split will be Enter (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm developing a discord bot using discord.js. It has a command that can store multi stuff with 1 command like

`!add Ex1 Ex2 Ex3`

the separator there is 1 space. I want it to be Enter, like

```
!add Ex1
Ex2
Ex3
```

The code I'm using is

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
module.exports.run = async (client,message,args) => {
const channelID = "661653664770818069";
const Store = require("data-store");
const things = new Store({ path: "things.json" });
const randomItem = require("random-item");
  
if (
  message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
    if (message.content.split(" ").length >= 2) {
      var attributes = message.content.split(" ");
      attributes.slice(2).forEach(thing => {
        things.union(attributes[1], thing);
      });
      message.channel.send("things added successfully.");
    } else {
      message.channel.send("please use: `!add (things)`");
    }
  }
};
```

Is this possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Split on `newline-operator`: `\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As possible you can split it with `'\n'`.
I think the best way is allow to use self command `!add` and then await for next message with list. You can do this with this code.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Store = require("data-store");
const things = new Store({ path: "things.json" });
const randomItem = require("random-item");

module.exports.run = async(client, message, args, item) => {
 if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return

      let useTips = new Discord.RichEmbed();
                useTips.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
                useTips.setDescription('Pls enter the list things separated by new line')
                useTips.setColor(0xdb001d)
      message.channel.send(useTips)
      const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
      await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 30000,errors: ['time']})
                .then(collected => {
                        let collection = collected.first();
                        let attributes = collection.content.split("\n");
                        if (attributes.length < 2) {
                            message.channel.send('You need add minimum two things')
                            return
                        }
                        attributes.slice(2).forEach(thing => {
                        things.union(attributes[1], thing);
                        });
                        message.channel.send('things added successfully.')
                })
                .catch(collected => {
          message.channel.send('Timed out');
                    return
                });
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, i will check it. The one way its error in this block. 



                       attributes.slice(2).forEach(thing => {
                        things.union(attributes[1], thing);
                        });`

Comment: so what sould i do to fix it and do like
!add list1

and than it will ask me to write the list and i will reply

thing1
thing2
thing3

and on the things.json fille going to be write

{
"list1": [
"thing1",
"thing2",
"thing3"
]
}

???

Comment: Sorry, i found the error `let collection = collected.fist();` must be `let collection = collected.first();`

Comment: About your const things = new Store({ path: "things.json" });
I don’t know what data structure you need. But as an option, you can simply use the `push` method with the required data. Do not forget to save the received Json, as data will be lost after the bot is turned off. You can use module `fs` and` fs.writeFileSync ("filePatchAndName", JSON.stringify (YOURJSONArray)) `to do that.

Comment: thank you so much!!! thats working, you really good man, than you brooo❤️❤️❤️

Comment: I am glad to help :)